# How to draw a circle on the cursor in Java without using every time the repaint method

Tags: java, graphics, repaint

I have written some code to draw a circle on the cursor every time I move it without repaint all the components of my Panel, but I don't really like my solution and I want to know if there are better solution to do that. 
This is my code:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
    import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class PnlMyPaintArea extends JPanel implements   MouseMotionListener{
    Point2D mousePos = null;            //position of the cursor at the current moving
    Point2D lastPos = null;             //position of the cursor at the last moving
    boolean state;
    int width = 30, height = 30;          //size of my circle
    public PnlMyPaintArea() {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        state = false;
    }

    public void drawCircle() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.fillOval((int)(mousePos.getX()-width/2), (int)(mousePos.getY()-height/2), width, height); 
    }


    //this method cancels the last circle drawn in the last moving 
    public void coverCircle() {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.clearRect((int)(lastPos.getX()-width/2), (int)(lastPos.getY()-height/2), width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePos = e.getPoint();
        if(state == true) {            //from the second moving on I cancel the old circle and draw the new one
            coverCircle();
            drawCircle();
        }
        else if(state == false) {       //at the first moving I only draw the circle
            drawCircle();
            state = true;
        }
        lastPos = mousePos;             
    }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you like it?? its fine!

Comment: You can't control when your panel will receive a repaint request, so you will likely run into many incorrect erasures/draws trying to do it this way, unless you make the draws using XOR mode of the Graphics.